# Auto Increment Field Contains Random Negative Integer Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 1.0 and SQL Server. I have an auto increment column in one of my entities. I have been unable to insert data into the database. My checks revealed that the auto increment column holds a random integer number.

I have no idea where these values are coming from. I find this quite strange because just after instantiating I pass the various values in minus the ID field but this somehow shows up with a negative value

Comment: You can check your table definition on your SQL Server with this: sp_help 'FullTableName' and can you show your entity class or fluent api ?

Comment: What I mean is that I leave the ID field alone since I expect the database to handle that

Comment: public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Tier> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(a => a.TierID);
            builder.Property(a => a.TierID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.HasOne(a => a.Country)
                .WithMany(a => a.Tiers)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryID);
        }

Comment: With auto increment do you mean an identity? In that case you need to use this method: entity.Property(p => p.TierID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

Comment: yeah, an Identity column

Comment: builder.Property(a => a.TierID).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn(); is not working